# What's the difference between eth and cpp-ethereum?

Tags: cpp-ethereum, linux, ubuntu

In Ubuntu, what's the difference between `apt-get install eth` vs. `apt-get install cpp-ethereum`?

They both seem to install the same packages but seemingly not the same versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context `eth` is the more updated version of `cpp-ethereum`.

`cpp-ethereum` [was renamed to `TurboEthereum`](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/releases/tag/1.0rc1) in September 2015 by the core dev team.

`TurboEthereum` is now [a full software suite](https://github.com/ethereum/guide) that includes:

- **++eth** (`eth`), the mainline Ethereum CLI client
- AlethOne (`alethone`), mainline miner
- AlethZero (`alethzero`), powerful Ethereum client
- Mix (`mix`), DApp IDE
- and a number of other tools.

Comment: The naming gets quite confusing if you add "webthree" to the list :)

Comment: @5chdn I enjoy using Safari when browsing rhe Ethereum github because it really feels like it.